# Exclude records that meet certain criteria by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I'm in need of some brainstorming. I have built a query that shows me what I need. However the ask now is to use this list of records and exclude records based on a certain criteria.

This is my current output from the query  built:

```
Patient | Action | Date
james   | REG    | 2019/01/01
James   | CUR    | 2019/01/15
Jacon   | REG    | 2019/01/12
Jacob   | REG    | 2019/01/13
Main    | CUR    | 2019/01/01
Main    | REG    | 2019/01/05
Lucy    | REG    | 2019/01/08
Lucy    | CUR    | 2019/01/09
Lucy    | CUR    | 2019/01/10
```

Based on the sample data from above I want to remove any patients where the first record is 'REG' and the following Action is 'CUR'. So in this example I only want to remove James.

Any Ideas on what I should do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you define the *next* record? You need a column to order the records.

Comment: Why don't you want LUCY removed too? Because of second CUR?

Comment: * I have built a query that shows me what I need*: please show us your current query, as well as your sample data, and expected result.

Comment: what do you have against Lucy?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, Correct.  I don't want to remove Lucy because of the second CUR

Comment: @JamieD77, she is not cool enough haha!

Comment: @WWaldo so can I say any Patient has more than 2 records will NOT be removed even though first=REG and second=CUR ? I couldn't get the exact pattern for lucy

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, Correct. If a patient has only two records and the first one is REG and the next one is CUR then I do not want them removed.  Let me edit the table and add in a date for when the record occurs. that might help

Comment: @WWaldo I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli You Rock!! Thank you fro your help!! This is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please group your data first by using `dense_rank` and `row_number`, then benefiting from temp tables, get the data you are looking for.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Patient VARCHAR(50), Action VARCHAR(3))
Insert INTO #temp VALUES
('james','REG'),
('james','CUR'),
('Jacob','REG'),
('Jacob','REG'),
('Main','CUR'),
('Main','REG'),
('Lucy','REG'),
('Lucy','CUR'),
('Lucy','CUR')

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Patient ASC) GroupNo,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY Patient ORDER BY Patient ASC) GroupOrder
INTO #PatientsWithGroup
FROM #temp

SELECT MIN(c1.GroupNo) GroupNo
INTO #PatsToEliminate
FROM #PatientsWithGroup c1
INNER JOIN #PatientsWithGroup c2 ON c1.GroupNo=c2.GroupNo
WHERE (c1.GroupOrder=1 AND c1.Action='REG') AND (c2.GroupOrder = 2 AND c2.Action='CUR')
HAVING COUNT(c1.Patient)<3

SELECT *
FROM #PatientsWithGroup p
WHERE p.GroupNo NOT IN (SELECT GroupNo FROM #PatsToEliminate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to look ahead.

```
CREATE TABLE #Patients (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Patient varchar(50),
    [Action] varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Patients (Patient, [Action])
VALUES
('james', 'REG'),
('James', 'CUR'),
('Jacon', 'REG'),
('Jacob', 'REG'),
('Main',  'CUR'),
('Main',  'REG'),
('Lucy',  'REG'),
('Lucy',  'CUR'),
('Lucy',  'CUR');

SELECT * FROM #Patients;

WITH 
    PatientWithNextAction AS (
        SELECT 
            Patient,
            [Action],
            LEAD([Action]) OVER(PARTITION BY Patient ORDER BY ID) NextAction
        FROM 
            #Patients 
    )
DELETE 
FROM 
    #Patients 
WHERE 
    Patient IN (
        SELECT
            Patient
        FROM
            PatientWithNextAction
        WHERE
            [Action] = 'REG'
            AND NextAction = 'CUR'
    );

SELECT * FROM #Patients;


DROP TABLE #Patients;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select 1 as ordre, 'james' as Patient, 'REG' as Action into #tmp
union select 2,'James', 'CUR'
union select 3,'Jacon', 'REG'
union select 4,'Jacob', 'REG'
union select 5,'Main' , 'CUR'
union select 6,'Main' , 'REG'
union select 7,'Lucy' , 'REG'
union select 8,'Lucy' , 'CUR'
union select 9,'Lucy' , 'CUR'

;with cte as
(
select ordre, Patient, [Action], RANK () OVER ( 
 PARTITION BY Patient
 ORDER BY  ordre
 ) Patient_order  from #tmp a 
)

select * from cte a where not exists(select 1 from cte b where a.Patient = b.Patient and b.Patient_order = 1 and Action = 'REG'
                            and exists(select 1 from cte c where c.Patient = b.Patient and c.Patient_order = 2 and Action = 'CUR')
                            )
```